# Alternatives for HTML5 menu element of type toolbar?

Tags: html, menu

I am trying to create a menu using HTML5 ( type toolbar ). It turns out that no browser currently supports the toolbar type. (Thanks Zach for pointing me at this) What would be the best implementation that works for Chrome and Firefox ?

Currently, I am thinking about continuing using the menu element as per HTML5 spec and using CSS to style it as needed and JS to add behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a toolbar that works in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Comment: why not just use `<nav role="navigation">...</nav>`?

Comment: nav is used for cross page navigation. the menu I am using is meant to change the state within the page.

Comment: @ZachSaucier: Thank you for pointing this out. Looking at http://caniuse.com/#search=menu again. it turns out that I miss read the capabilities: Firefox only has some support for the context type not the toolbar type as I initially thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following mailing list posting explains the current intent for menus of type toolbar:

> - Toolbars are nothing more than a  with the element name . 
>     There's no magic at all, no special content model, it's all CSS for 
>     styling, you use regular form controls to fill the toolbar.

from http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Dec/0264.html

Hence, I am daring to say, that I can use menu for all browsers, even if a browser does not explicitly support the HTML5 semantic of the menu element, because it will still display it as a block since the user agents, I have checked ( i.e. firefox,chrome,safari,ie) , style menu with display:block.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a bit of jquery, and if i understand your question, then a simple

```
<div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid">Summary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="star" class="ui-btn-active">Favs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear">Setup</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

would do the trick.

read more about navbar widgets here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/navbar/

Comment: This would remove the semantic markup, that HTML5 provides and replaces it with a JQuery specific semantic. I am looking for a solution that allows me to keep the HTML5 semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [bootstrap menu](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/), it works (IMO) much like a toolbar, and it's got a wide support on a lot of browsers.

It's also got [glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use) so you can give your buttons icons beside the labels easily